# fb-login-button makes page jump up and down until it loads

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I added Facebook login to one of my websites. However, until the Facebook button switches from text to an actual fb-login-button, my site's height is larger than it should be and once the facebook button shows up, it goes back to normal. Does anyone know why that is? Should I modify anything? Here's the code for it:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" style="float: left; overflow:hidden;" size="large" scope="user_about_me, email">Use Facebook Account to Login</div>
```

I figure it's because of xfbml, but I really want to use it so I don't understand why it's jumping up and down right before showing it's proper color scheme.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a max-height:50px or something close to that value in your css.
That would force the fb button to not expand and increase height temporarily to load the iframe.

You can try something like this:
**HTML**

```
<div class="fb-login-button fb-no-jump" size="large" scope="user_about_me, email">
Use Facebook Account to Login</div>
```

And the **CSS**:

```
.fb-no-jump {
    display:block;
    max-height:50px /*change as per requirement*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Yohann's answer I found that "overflow" and "display" (with the !important) are essential.
The code below works for me. No jumping of the button nor the content below it.

```
.fb-login-button-no-jump {
    width: 123px;
    height: 39px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block !important;
}
```